# Can't access Class in some other class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, web-applications

I have one class file JobSeekerBO it's has variable

```
   string _username = string.Empty;
   string _password = string.Empty;
```

and i set value as below

```
public string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set { _username = value; }
}

public string Password
{
    get { return _password; }
    set { _password = value; }
}
```

but problem is that that variable i access in another class file  `class1.cs` i create object of that class file

```
JobSeekerBO objBO = new JobSeekerBO();
```

but i can't access `Username` and `Password` in `class1.cs` class file from my `JobSeekerBO.cs` file

I also try to make that variable public as per below

```
public string _username = string.Empty;
public string _password = string.Empty;
```

same class file varible without public access modifier we can access in `file1.aspx.cs` file

So please tell me how to access variable and method of one `.cs` file to another `.cs` file.

[image: Page Code]

Comment: What error message you receive?

Comment: objBO.Username should do the trick

Comment: You should not make the variable public but the appropriate property.

Comment: error or problem is that when i create object of `JobSeekerBO.cs` file `JobSeekerBO objBO = new JobSeekerBO();` after that definitely  access that string `Username` and `Password`, but it's not show up in `objBO.` @Steve

Comment: show complete code of your class from starting to end.

Comment: You are missing something basic here, post both classes (or at least the broken method that creates objBo). Oh and make _username and _password private again, that's complete non-starter of a solution.

Comment: i think you have a namespace problem. please check post your complete code, and verify that both class have the same namespace

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi: You are doing it at the wrong place. you should do it (Setting the proeprty value) in a method. See my updated answer

Comment: Your code is correct. I understand you have edit it after checking answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not access `_username` and `_password` outside your class because they are [private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) by default. That means they are accessible only within the body of the class. But you have the **Public properties** which `sets` and `gets` values on these fields. So you should use those public Properties.

```
JobSeekerBO objBO = new JobSeekerBO();
objBo.Username="someusername";
objBo.Password="myPassword";
```

Assuming your class look like this

```
public class JobSeekerBO
{ 
   string _username = string.Empty;
   string _password= string.Empty;      

   public string Username
   {
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; }
   }        
   public string Password
   {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; }
   }    
}
```

> Generally, you should use fields only for variables that have private
>   or protected accessibility. Data that your class exposes to client
>   code should be provided through methods, properties and indexers.

More about class fields [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) in msdn

**EDIT: After looking at your code.**

You are trying to set the Public property value in a wrong place. You can not do it there. You should do it in a method ( even in your Constructor is fine).

```
public class MailRepositary
{
  JobSeekerBO objBO = new JobSeekerBO();
  public MailRepositary()
  {
      objBo.UserName="works from constructor";
  }
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
      objBo.UserName="works from method also";
  }
}
```

Comment: but can't get Username as `objBo.Username` its shows error that Error 2 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi: You have these Public Properties in your JobSeekerBO class. Correct ? Then it should be working. please post your entire classs structue

Comment: OK its syntactic error.  @BrijeshGandhi please add all your code...you just add `;` symbol where it shouldnt be

Comment: thanks @Shyju it works...so method of one class can be accessed only in function

Answer (score 1):

The class **JobSeekerBO** may be out of the `namespace`!

The **JobSeekerBO** class must be in the same `namespace` from where you are accessing it.

If **JobSeekerBO** is in another or out of `namespace` you would have to **include** the `namespace` that contains `JobSeekerBO` or you would have to write **JobSeekerBO** in the same `namespace`!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get or set UserName and Password by simply doing like this.

```
var objBO = new JobSeekerBO();
var username = objBo.UserName;
var password = objBo.Password;
```

There is no need for the "backend" variables to be public, these can be private.

Answer (score 1):

There are few scenarios where you will not be able to do:

1. the namespaces has not been referred properly
2. the class u have specified (with property) may be set as internal or protected internal
   if so, please mention it as public if the two classes are of different name spaces

Please verify them.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a static class:

1. They only contain static members.
2. They cannot be instantiated.

eg.

```
JobSeekerBO.UserName;   

//accessing the non-public member of the class with the public property
```

And if not a static class then it should have `public` class then it must be access by initiating the object.

```
JobSeekerBO objBO = new JobSeekerBO();
objBo.Username = "XXXXXXX";
objBo.Password = "XXXXXXX";
```

Or

There may be a namespace problem. like the class is inside the namespace so to have an access of this you have to make reference to this.

```
using XYZ;
```